# How do you put integers within a range in Java?

Tags: java, range, average

Though I am sure that this answer is simple, I am not sure that is asked of me for this assignment. Here is the full code that I have written (so just a return!) as well as the instructions that were given:

```
package code;

/**
 * This class contains a variety of methods that will be used throughout the Ratings and Reviews
 * project.
 */

public class Utilities{

/**
 * Computes the average of two ratings
 *
 * @param rating0 An integer rating in the range of 1-5 inclusive
 * @param rating1 An integer rating in the range of 1-5 inclusive
 * @return the average of rating0 and rating1 as a double
 */
public double averageRating(int rating0, int rating1){

    return ((rating0 + rating1) / 2); // Don't forget to replace this return statement with your own
}
```

Sorry for bad structure upon pasting it. I think my return is suitable for what is being done, provided that the rating could be just anything. I know that it can only be between 1-5, though, so how would one go about specifying that?

Comment: What are the instructions ?

Comment: As a note, this is early on in a beginners class, so I am looking for the most simple solution to this.

Comment: You are not describing the problem, causing this post to be reported as low quality probably. I'm struggling to connect the title to averageRating as well without more info.

Comment: The instructions start with "Computes the average of two ratings". This is a beginning class and that is all we have to do for this question.

Comment: At the end I said that the problem is that I do not know how to make it so that integers can only be within the range 1-5.

Comment: You should divide by `2.0` rather than `2` if you want a double average rather than an int average.

Comment: I am sorry if this is unclear, but this is all that we have been given. I'm just trying to put integers within a range of 1-5.

Comment: Thanks, khelwood, still learning.

Comment: Sorry to everyone who found this confusing. This is all the instruction we are given. We aren't even given a description of the "project", just this code with these small blocks of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

How about throwing an `InvalidArgumentException` if the range is violated?

e.g.

```
public double averageRating(int rating0, int rating1){
    if (rating0 < 1 || rating0 > 5 || rating1 < 1 || rating1 > 5) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Rating out of range");
    }

    return ((rating0 + rating1) / 2.0); // Don't forget to replace this return statement with your own
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the return value is double and the parameters are integers using integer division

Comment: What you did there with the "if", giving the ratings a range, is there any way I could do that without it being in a loop? Is there any way to just state that range as you did there?

Comment: This seems like a beginners class. I doubt they are learning about throwing `Exceptions`.  Just use `System.out.println()` for the error message and return something like -1.

Comment: @ParkerFinch It's not in a loop. An `if` statement is not the same as a loop. I think you're asking if there's a way to do it without checking all 4 cases, but I don't think there is since you have to check two endpoints for two arguments (= 4 checks).

Comment: Thanks everyone! Helpful.